# Pass php variables from a method to outside class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this class

```
class TableInvoices extends WP_List_Table {
    function prepare_items() {
        $sumOwed = 'Anything';
        $sumTotal = 'Something';
    }
}
```

How can I echo $sumTotal outside the class ?

Thanks

EDIT:

@Eisa Adil solutions worked very well, also this worked:

```
class TableInvoices extends WP_List_Table {
    public $sumOwed;
    public $sumTotal;

    function prepare_items() {
        $sumOwed = 'Anything';
        $sumTotal = 'Something';

        $this->sumOwed = $sumOwed;
        $this->sumTotal = $sumTotal;
    }
}

$sum = new TableInvoices();
$sum->prepare_items();

echo $sum->sumOwed . '<br>';
echo $sum->sumTotal;
```

Comment: Either by returning those values, or by setting public properties rather than locally scoped variables in the method

Comment: "Return" will dedicate the whole function for those 2 variables, so you suggest $this->sumOwed = $sumOwed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TableInvoices extends WP_List_Table {
    public static $sumTotal;
    public function prepare_items() {

        sumOwed = 'Anything';
        self::sumTotal = 'Something';
    }
}
echo TableInvoices::$sumTotal;
```

Use static variables. This would help you access methods and properties without instantiating an object.

Obviously it'll give undefined so you'll need to instantiate an object and run `prepare_items()` or statically access that too.

```
class TableInvoices extends WP_List_Table {
    public static $sumTotal;
    public static function prepare_items() {
        self::sumTotal = 'Something';
    }
}
TableInvoices::prepare_items();
echo TableInvoices::$sumTotal;
```

Comment: This worked, and thank you for the explanation, it is more clear now.